# php access database from multiple running scripts without duplicate select

Tags: php, database

I have a script that is posting pictures to Facebook profiles. It takes a really long time and usually crashes before its done. What I need to do is run multiple versions of the script from a cron job and have many processing at the same time so they post faster.

**MY ISSUE IS I hope to run multiple scripts at the same time to speed up the posting. 
Selecting a user, and updating to sent.** However, I need to make sure the script does not try to process two users at the same time or select the same user twice from a database while that is potentially being processed by another running script,  thus causing two photos to be posted on a users wall.

My question pertains to efficiency in calling the database and creating a way to run multiple scripts on this database at the same time to increase post speed.

I have a field called tweetSent and this is set to notSent. After it posts the photo it updates to 'sent'. But this takes nearly 7 seconds for each post and if another script accessed the database while it was processing one user it would double post on that users wall because the field in the table would still be 'notSent'

My code says select a user where tweetSent is 'notSent'. I have an idea that might fix my issue. I was thinking about updating it right away to 'sending' so another multiple cron job running at the same time will select this user. Then when its done posting it will update to 'sent'.

I also see another issue with my code. It seems to SELECT ALL users at the same time and then run a WHILE LOOP and post from this loop. It seems to me maybe I should just select ONE user where 'tweetSent' is 'notSent' and then update it to 'sending' right away and when sent then update it to sent.  And maybe put this single call to a database in a function and call that function in a while loop? Not sure.

My question to all the great coders on Stack is, I am wondering if this is the best means to do this or maybe someone knows of a better and more efficient way to do what I am try to achieve.

Below is the database portion of my present script that runs really slowly and which will not allow me to RUN multiple versions of this script without double posts.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE tokenExpireDate > \"$date\" AND tweetSent='notSent' ";


$retval = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
{

    PostPhoto($fbId, $access_token);
    PostText($fbId, $access_token);


    echo "<hr>";

    $query = "UPDATE user SET tweetSent='sent' WHERE fbID='$fbId'";
    mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());

}
```

UPDATE:

I came up with a 'potential' solution. Would this work or is this silliness?
I seems to work HOWEVER WHEN I RUN THE SCRIPT AT THE SAME TIME in 3 different windows
it only runs them in order and can't connect to the database at the same time. It seems.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE tokenExpireDate > \"$date\" AND tweetSent='notSent' LIMIT 5";
$retval = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
    {
        $ID[] = $row['fbID'];
    }

echo count($ID);

for($i=0; count($ID)>$i;$i++)
{   
sendTweet($ID[$i]);
}

function sendTweet($ID)
{
    // QUES THE USER ID
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE tokenExpireDate > \"$date\" AND tweetSent='notSent' AND fbID = '$ID' LIMIT 7";
    $retval = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($retval) >= 1 ) 
    { 
            $query = "UPDATE user SET tweetSent='sending' WHERE fbID='$ID'";
            mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());  
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
            {
                $fbId = $row['fbID'];
                $type = $row['type'];
                $access_token = $row['longToken'];


                PostPhoto($fbId, $access_token);
                PostText($fbId, $access_token);


                /// UPDATES TO SENT
                $query = "UPDATE user SET tweetSent='sent' WHERE fbID='$fbId'";
            mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be after a messaging queue? http://www.rabbitmq.com

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- You need to understand where the bottleneck is in the process. Just guessing, I would imagine that it would be the actual POST to Facebook. You should focus you efforts on making this part more efficient or you will never get as much throughput as you like.
- Don't resort to using multiple overlapping cron scripts until you have exhausted other approaches.
- Assuming that the POST to Facebook is the performance block, you could consider using `curl_mulit_exec()` or similar to make multiple calls to Facebook in parallel.  I have a simple REST client class in PHP I have set up to do this.  You can feel free to use it, or simply look at the implementation of `curl_multi_exec()` for thoughts on how you may do this. Here is the link - https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client
- When working with your database, you should consider using LIMIT statement.  In this manner, you can work with a smaller subset of your table at a time, updating successful POST's for this subgroup of records before going on to the next. For example, say you used `curl_multi_exec()` to make 10 posts at a time to Facebook, you could select 10 rows at a time from the DB, make 10 parallel Facebook requests for those rows, update the posting results to those rows, and then move on to the next set of records
- You may also consider using some sort of a queuing system for this, as this is in essence what you are trying to do here is build a queue.  If that seems like a tall task for you, then perhaps start with the steps above and move to the queue if you are finding this is still not meeting your needs.  Of course if you expect to need to do this sort of operation for large volumes of records, you may want to think twice and just go straight to queue, as using relational DB as a queue is not ideal for large traffic volumes.

Comment: I posted a work around in my question. Would this work? Right now I only have 1900 users but it could get to 10k or more soon so I need to beef up the processing and run multiple scripts.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau You can keep throwing workarounds at the problem all you want, but until you understand your bottleneck, you are not going to reach a reasonable solution. Also you should think about what your tolerance is for time in which you must process these 1900 or whatever records. I would still contend that using multiple script executions should be a last ditch effort.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this would be to change your photo posting system to a [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) as it sounds awfully like one.

[IronMQ](http://www.iron.io/mq) is a great starting point and is one the easiest to use, from there you can explore other queue systems. You also get a great free tier. Other ones are [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

Queues defeat your problem by removing or 'popping' the message off the queue and then processing. If an error occurs or fails to process the message then it is put back onto the queue.

By taking it off the queue you ensure that no other process can access it.

You might also want to take a look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

---

If you don't want to change your system to a queue system then you want to look into transactions and record locking. Setting a record to `processing` could allow two processes to pull the record at the same time and then both update it to `processing` one after the other, resulting in both processes posting the photo.

Answer (score -1):

singleton:

```
private static $MysqlAdapter;


private $con;

private function __construct() {
$this->con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB_DB);
if ($this->con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->con->connect_errno . ") " . $this->con->connect_error;
} else {
    $this->con->set_charset("utf8");
}
}

public static function getInstance() {
if (self::$MysqlAdapter == NULL) {
    self::$MysqlAdapter = new MysqlAdapter();
}
return self::$MysqlAdapter;
}
```